# What is the easiest way to remove the papery covers from the peanuts?

Tags: peanuts

Intention is to make peanut butter. What is the easiest way to achieve the said aim?

Comment: Related, but not a dupe (there are other ways besides blanching): http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11611/how-to-blanch-and-peel-nuts?lq=1

Answer (score 4):

Here's someone with a lot of experience doing it! [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbmPNJEzfaM)

Dropping the peanuts into boiling water for a couple of minutes, then draining and rinsing in cold water is supposed to make them easier and quicker to peel.

I've heard freezing them overnight helps.

One method method that I have actually done is to peel them by rubbing them with a towel while they are still warm from being roasted. The trick there is to only roast small batches at a time so you can get to them all before they cool.